# Service Bus netTcpRelayBinding faster than regular netTcpBinding?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay, nettcprelaybinding

I have noticed a strange situation. I am writing a paper for class about Service Bus relay component. I decided to test what impact does it have on performance (there is a "client <--> sb relay <--> service" instead of "client <--> service" connection, so there must be a delay). Suprisingly, test with large input data (~1.5 MB of data per request as input, service returns single integer as output) proved application using SB Relay to be 4 times faster (500ms vs 2000ms). I honestly have no idea where did these results come from. I tested client app on another machine (service is still hosted on Azure VM), but with same results. I tested if requests are coming through (if there is any "cache-like" mechanism, but everything seems to be ok.
Does anyone have an idea why is relayed connection faster than direct?

Thanks for any help

Comment: For a brief moment I thought that it might be due to number of connections. There is only one channel open between SB Relay and WCF Service in relayed mode, but in direct mode there is one channel per client and maybe just SB Relay is better at handling multiple connections than WCF hosted on VM. But i actually use one channel (both in Relay and Direct scenarios, i create 5 threads, but they share a ClientChannel...